# Trouble for "move" when I tried use multiple thread

Tags: rust, thread-safety

I am new for rust and I get some move trouble when I want to use multiple thread to do something; and it seems I can't "real" copy some data;

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread;


pub fn frequency(input: &str, some_chars: Vec<char>){
    let all_chars = input.chars();
    let mut  unique_chars = vec![];
    for ci in all_chars {
        if ! unique_chars.contains(&ci) {
            unique_chars.push(ci);
        }
    }
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

    for tci in some_chars {
        let tx_copy = tx.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut chars_count= 0 as usize;
            let all_chars_copy = all_chars.clone();
            for aci in all_chars_copy {
                if aci == tci {
                    chars_count += 1;
                }
            }
            tx_copy.send((tci, chars_count));
        });
    }

    for received in rx {
        println!("Got: {:?}", received);
    }

}


fn main() {
    let a_string = "dsfsdfdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfw4eer34fdefd";
    frequency(a_string, vec!['a', 'b', 'c']);
}
```

The compile error is as below; when I want to move some data on mutiple thread, i should copy some data to "move", but it seems look like failed; shall I get some advice for resolve this problem?

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of function
  --> src\main.rs:18:9
   |
6  |   pub fn frequency(input: &str, some_chars: Vec<char>){
   |                    -----  - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
   |                    |
   |                    `input` is a reference that is only valid in the function body
...
18 | /         thread::spawn(move || {
19 | |             let mut chars_count= 0 as usize;
20 | |             let all_chars_copy = all_chars.clone();
21 | |             for aci in all_chars_copy {
...  |
26 | |             tx_copy.send((tci, chars_count));
27 | |         });
   | |          ^
   | |          |
   | |__________`input` escapes the function body here
   |            argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `all_chars`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues:

1. You already move `all_chars` before you even start the first thread here:

```rust
for ci in all_chars {
```

Since it's cheap you can just create a new one like this:

```rust
for ci in input.chars() {
```

2. Your'e trying to clone `all_chars` inside of the closure but at that point you already moved it, so either `clone` it outside:

```rust
        thread::spawn({
            let all_chars = all_chars.clone();
            move || {
                let mut chars_count = 0 as usize;
                for aci in all_chars {
                    if aci == tci {
                        chars_count += 1;
                    }
                }
                tx_copy.send((tci, chars_count));
            }
        });
```

or just create it from scratch again:

```rust
        thread::spawn(move || {
                let mut chars_count = 0 as usize;
                for aci in input.chars() {
                    if aci == tci {
                        chars_count += 1;
                    }
                }
                tx_copy.send((tci, chars_count));
            }
);
```

3. You get bitten by the fact that you're using `.chars()` borrows the original `&str` so it's referencing local variables, to overcome that you can just use `thread::scope` because you read the contents of the threads at the end of the function anyways:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread;

pub fn frequency(input: &str, some_chars: Vec<char>) {
    let mut unique_chars = vec![];
    for ci in input.chars() {
        if !unique_chars.contains(&ci) {
            unique_chars.push(ci);
        }
    }
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

    thread::scope(|s| {
        for tci in some_chars {
            let tx_copy = tx.clone();
            s.spawn(move || {
                let mut chars_count = 0 as usize;
                for aci in input.chars() {
                    if aci == tci {
                        chars_count += 1;
                    }
                }
                tx_copy.send((tci, chars_count));
            });
        }
    });

    for received in rx {
        println!("Got: {:?}", received);
    }
}
```

4. Of course [Masklinn is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75543547/442760) you don't need the channel at all.

```rust
use std::thread;

pub fn frequency(input: &str, some_chars: Vec<char>) {
    let mut unique_chars = vec![];
    for ci in input.chars() {
        if !unique_chars.contains(&ci) {
            unique_chars.push(ci);
        }
    }

    thread::scope(|s| {
        let mut ts = Vec::with_capacity(some_chars.len());
        for tci in some_chars {
            ts.push(s.spawn(move || {
                let mut chars_count = 0 as usize;
                for aci in input.chars() {
                    if aci == tci {
                        chars_count += 1;
                    }
                }
                (tci, chars_count)
            }));
        }
        for h in ts {
            let (tci, chars_count) = h.join().unwrap();
            println!("Got: {:?}", (tci, chars_count));
        }
    });
}
```

5. Another problem with the channel implementation that I didn't notice at first is that you never drop the initial `tx` so the `for` loop waits forever for new input. An easy fix would be to add `drop(tx);` right after you spawned all the threads so `rx` gets exhausted after all the sub threads finish.

Comment: Yes the original `tx` stays open so `rx` might still theoretically receive something, see 5. Of course here it's just a dead lock.

Answer (score 1):

> The compile error is as below; when I want to move some data on mutiple thread, i should copy some data to "move", but it seems look like failed; shall I get some advice for resolve this problem?

In your code, `all_chars.clone()` is inside the thread closures, so the code must borrow `all_chars`, then whenever the thread runs (possibly 6 months from now as far as the compiler is concerned) the copy will be created.

For this to work, you need to copy the item before the closure, and move *the copy* into the new thread, exactly as you do with `tx`. A common pattern for this is the [precise capture clause](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2018/04/24/rust-pattern-precise-closure-capture-clauses/):

```rust
thread::spawn({
    let tx = tx.clone();
    let all_chars = all_chars.clone();
    move || {
        let mut chars_count= 0 as usize;
        for aci in all_chars {
            if aci == tci {
                chars_count += 1;
            }
        }
        tx.send((tci, chars_count));
    }
});
```

Except that won't actually work, because the value returned from `str::chars` *borrows the string. So for the code to work you really need to copy the string itself (possibly to an `Arc` in order to share it between threads rather than re-copy it every time), so each thread can "own" the input string.

A fine alternative for this specific case is [scoped threads](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html), because the API is defined in such a way that the thread can borrow from its caller, and thus there's no issue borrowing `input`.

Also assuming your actual code is similar (in that every thread pushes a single value on the queue), you don't even need the mpsc channel: `join`-ing a rust thread (scoped or not) returns its value, so instead of looping on `rx` you could just loop on the threads, `join()` them, and return the data from the threads.

Finally your code is broken in a way which would make scoped threads fail: `str::chars` returns [an iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html), this means following the initial iteration (`for ci in all_chars`) all the data in `all_chars` has been consumed even if the iterator itself has not, so further iteration will do nothing (the iteration will end immediately with no items yielded). Rust iterators are one shot, they're not "restartable".